# Finding highest value in laravel eloquent relationship

Tags: php, laravel

So I'm basically trying to find values of selected results (can vary) and then compare them to find the highest specific column value dependant on how many results are selected.

Here's how I gather my results:

```php
public function index($id = null, $name = null, $id2 = null, $name2 = null, $id3 = null, $name3 = null)
{
    $users = [];
    $jsonStats = [];
    if (isset($id)) {
        $users[] = Users::query()->findOrFail($id);
        if (isset($id2)) {
            $users[] = Users::query()->findOrFail($id2);
            if (isset($id3)) {
                $users[] = Users::query()->findOrFail($id3);
            }
        }
    }
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $jsonStats[] = $user->stats->asArray();
    }
    return view('frontend.index', [
        'users' => $users,
        'stats_json' => $jsonStats
    ]);
}
```

So as you can see I finally get an Eloquent result within the `users[]` array, although I then need to find the highest value from within a relationship called `stats`

I've attempted to do the following to no avail:

```html
{{ max(array_column($users->stats, 'stat1')) }}
```

Which throws the following:

> Trying to get property 'stats' of non-object

**EDIT**
My `$user->stats->asArray();` function returns the following:

```php
public function asArray()
{
    return [
        'stat1' => [
            [
                'id' => 'attribute1',
                'name' => 'Attribute1',
                'type' => 'main',
                'value' => $this->attr1Value
            ],
            [
                'id' => 'attribute2',
                'name' => 'Attribute2',
                'type' => 'main',
                'value' => $this->attr2Value
            ],
            [
                'id' => 'attribute3',
                'name' => 'Attribute3',
                'type' => 'main',
                'value' => $this->attr3Value
            ]
        ]
    ];
}
```

When trying to find the max value from this array, I've tried the following:

```html
{{ max(array_column($stats_json['stat1'][0], 'value')) }}
```

Comment: if `$user` isn't an object than it might be null, try to log something `info($id);` under `if(isset($id)) {` to verify that the if block isn't completely skipped

Comment: @Saly3301 users will always have a result based on how it's accessed, this error also came from when 2 `users` was set

Comment: no, if no id is set, the if statement will be skipped and `$users` will be an empty array, means you will be iterating null values

Comment: Also you can't access property of an array `$users->stats` <--- This will always throw an error

Comment: @Saly3301 okay so how would I find the max value?

Comment: `max($jsonStats);` should do it given it's supposed to be an array of the stats value of users

Comment: @Saly3301 I've added an edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're checking if the `$id` is set then it's optional and the foreach block will try to access a property `stats` of what could be `null`, make the iteration conditional as well

```php
public function index($id = null, $name = null, $id2 = null, $name2 = null, $id3 = null, $name3 = null)
{
    $users = [];
    $jsonStats = [];
    if (isset($id)) {
        $users[] = Users::query()->findOrFail($id);
        if (isset($id2)) {
            $users[] = Users::query()->findOrFail($id2);
            if (isset($id3)) {
                $users[] = Users::query()->findOrFail($id3);
            }
        }
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $jsonStats[] = $user->stats->asArray();
        }
    }
    return view('frontend.index', [
        'users' => $users,
        'stats_json' => $jsonStats
    ]);
}
```

You could also use the `optional` helper function to avoid errors upon trying to access properties of non objects

```php
$jsonStats[] = optional($user)->stats->asArray();
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

First We get laravel eloquent relationship query.
Ex:

```
'$data' => [
        [
            'id' => '1',
            'name' => 'subject1',
            'type' => 'T',
            'value' => $this->Value
        ],
        [
            'id' => '2',
            'name' => 'subject2',
            'type' => 'M',
            'value' => $this->Value
        ],
        [
            'id' => '3',
            'name' => 'subject2',
            'type' => 'T',
            'value' => $this->Value
        ]
    ]
```

We can get max value someting like this

```
$max1 = max(array_column($data, 'value')) // only get value max


foreach ($data as $array) {
     if (in_array($array['value'],$max1)) {
         return $array;
     }
}
```

> That return value is the highest value in laravel eloquent relationship